# Do I need a MySQL sub query? How can I get these results?

Tags: mysql

First, the table names and layouts:

[image: table names & layouts]

Here are my desired results:

[image: Desired Results]

Here is the 'got ya' (trick) I guess..

I will only be passing a (dynamic) imis_id/user_id  (col names currently not matching on one table)...

So a lookup (select) will need to be done on the relations table for that passed in (dynamic) id.. and where current_org = 1.

This will get/give me the target org_id in which I need to grab all user info (that are associated with the org_id).. and all org details.

Here is one weak/failed attempt:  (it uses a hardcoded org_id) which is not valid.. I need to ONLY pass in the user_id/imis_id.. and where current_org = 1 to get the target org_id.

```
SELECT genealogy_orgs.org_id, genealogy_orgs.org_name, 
genealogy_relations.user_id, genealogy_relations.relation_type, genealogy_relations.start_year, genealogy_relations.end_year, 
genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_users.full_name 
FROM genealogy_orgs 
INNER JOIN genealogy_relations ON genealogy_orgs.org_id = genealogy_relations.org_id 
INNER JOIN genealogy_users ON genealogy_relations.user_id = genealogy_users.imis_id 
WHERE genealogy_orgs.org_id = '84864';
```

Here is another failed attempt (which only returns 1 row).. but uses the correct criteria:

```
SELECT 
genealogy_relations.org_id, 
genealogy_relations.user_id, genealogy_relations.relation_type, genealogy_relations.start_year, genealogy_relations.end_year, 
genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_users.full_name,
genealogy_orgs.org_name
FROM genealogy_relations
INNER JOIN genealogy_orgs ON genealogy_relations.org_id  = genealogy_orgs.org_id
INNER JOIN genealogy_users ON genealogy_relations.user_id = genealogy_users.imis_id 
WHERE genealogy_relations.user_id = '00003' AND genealogy_relations.current_org = '1';
```

At this point, I'm not even sure what I need to search for?  Is this where a 'sub-query/sub-select' comes into play?

My MySQL-fu is limited to very direct/plain-jane query types. This is getting to be more advanced than I am used to.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text we cant copy/paste from pictures [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: What you mean with "dynamic id" ? because your result return 3 rows for 3 different id

Comment: @Jaun Carlos Oropeza

1.) I mean '00003' will be a variable.. its hardcoded in the example.
2.) I dont understand how to use that rextester.com link

Comment: Then you need to be clear what value in your parameter produce that "desire" result, otherwise is just a guess. Right now your query seem to be ok, you set value to '00003' and get a single result because you only have one row

Comment: Rextester is simple. Just put your DDL statement there to create the tables in the DB and insert the sample data.

Comment: @Jaun Carlos Oropeza

Thanks.. I guess I'm not explaining it correctly then.

The desired results IMAGE is the correct desired output/outcome.

User: 00003, where current_org = '1'...  the org_id is: 84864

This is the value used to then get ALL org & user data for:  84864

Comment: @Jaun Carlos Oropeza

I am going to up your comment, as you are correct. I did not do anyone any justice by posting things as images.  Still not clear how to use that link you posted. (yes, I know you state its easy, but there are no directions)

Comment: @whispers Here's an example of how to use rexester in for your next question: http://rextester.com/SPIKH96809

Comment: Hi @whispers. I have undone your last rollback, my edit was a good one. If you disagree with it, please let me know, so I can involve a moderator. Please always ping editors if you intend to rollback, and ideally beforehand, so a good resolution can be found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `genealogy_relations` table with itself on `org_id`:

```
SELECT o.*, u.*
FROM genealogy_relations r1
JOIN genealogy_relations r2 ON r2.org_id = r1.org_id
JOIN genealogy_orgs o       ON o.org_id  = r2.org_id
JOIN genealogy_users u      ON u.imis_id = r2.user_id
WHERE r1.user_id = '00003'
  AND r1.current_org = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks...  the query doesnt compile/work..

 I get an error: "Unknown column 'o.user_id' in 'on clause' in query: "

Comment: That is why you should post a working example in rextester so we can test it.

Comment: @whispers It should be `o.org_id`. Fixed now

Comment: @Paul Spiegel  -

Boom!  You got it!  (answer accepted)..  sorry I made it more difficult with the images.. (not to up to speed on how to pass table layout/data stuff)

JOIN on itself?  (new to me!)  Thanks for sharing, and giving me some new stuff to read up on.

Comment: @whispers Yes you can join a table with itself if you give them distinct aliases like `r1` and `r2`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `genealogy_relations.user_id = '00003'` from the query and it should work

```
SELECT 
genealogy_relations.org_id, 
genealogy_relations.user_id, genealogy_relations.relation_type, genealogy_relations.start_year, genealogy_relations.end_year, 
genealogy_users.imis_id, genealogy_users.full_name,
genealogy_orgs.org_name
FROM genealogy_relations
INNER JOIN genealogy_orgs ON genealogy_relations.org_id  = genealogy_orgs.org_id
INNER JOIN genealogy_users ON genealogy_relations.user_id = genealogy_users.imis_id 
WHERE genealogy_relations.current_org = '1';
```

Comment: If I do that.. it pulls ALL current_org = '1' data..

Using the (bad) image examples from above..

User: 00003
After knowing this ID, and looking at what org_id is in the same ROW as the current_org = '1'..  this gives me a target org_id of: '84864

So I only need to get the data orgs matching "84864"...

Its like I need to get that 'target org_id" first.. then just do a normal JOIN query for my other data